# Trouble interpreting this wording

Tags: interpretation

> Expired temporary certificates. A three-year nonrenewable temporary certificate may be issued to an applicant who held a temporary certificate but did not hold a temporary certificate for the school year immediately preceding the school fiscal year for which the certificate is requested [...].

Note that school years run from August to July.

So suppose I held a certificate from September 2016 for the school year 2016-17, to when it expired at September 2019. Then...

Can I request and be issued a certificate for the school year 2020-2021, because I did not have a certificate for 2019-2020, or any part of? After all, my certificate expired on the school year 2018-2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming that you also "meets all requirements specified in paragraph (1)(a)". As you describe it, you did not hold a certificate (temporary or otherwise) for 2019-2020, which is the school year preceding 2020-2021.